# multiple urls in ssrs 2005 table textbox (using jump to URL)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a data in db like this

```
Category  Key    Products

Dairy     22       Milk

Dairy     22       Butter

Dairy     22       Cheez

Color     44       Red

Color     44       Green

Color     44       Blue

Shampoo    1       Pentene

Shampoo    1       H& D

Shampoo    1       Sunsilk

Drink      3       Pepsi

Drink      3       Coke
```

I want to display 4 rows in ssrs report according to each category. One row for each category. In the report I have one column that contain information about products. For example each product is just like a sub report. I want that the product information should contain multiple urls according to each product. Like if we take Dairy Category then "Product Information" field in the report should contain 3 links - one for Milk, 2nd for Butter and 3rd for Cheez.
When I right click on the "ProductInformation" textbox in the report (I am using table in the report and each cell is like textbox) then go to properties then Click on "Jump to URL" then I am only able to have one link only... I want to have multiple links per textbox in the ssrs table.

Comment: Title indicates that this is SSRS 2005, but tag is for SSRS 2008. Which are you using? Handling multiple URLs in a single textbox became possible in SSRS 2008.

Also, did you mean to say "I want to display 4 **columns** in the report according to each category?"

Comment: HI Jamie, According to this dataset, row will be 4 because unique categories are 4. My problem is to use multiple URLs in a single textbox in ssrs 2005. But you are saying that its not possible in ssrs 2005. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is acceptable to use three columns, you could use a Matrix Control.  I don't have a way to test this locally, so this is from memory.

Group by Category (which would be your row source) and set column source to Products.  For value, use an expression to grab the product name for that column:

```
=First(Fields!ProductName.Value)
```

This should display data like so:

```
Category  Key      Products

Dairy     22       Milk      Butter      Cheez
Color     44       Red       Green       Blue
Shampoo    1       Pentene   H& D        Sunsilk
Drink      3       Pepsi     Coke
```

Use an expression to dynamically set the URL for the data cell:

```
="http://www.myco.com/info.html?product=" & First(Fields!ProductName.Value)
```